# Access current div within loop

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to modify a loop to return the current div within an iteration, but the div is not being set using below code :

```
    $('#id div.columns).each(function() {

        var div = $(this).attr('argument');
        });         
    });
```

How can I get the div object within the loop ?

Comment: Use the `this` keyword. Given your code already does this, is there a specific problem you're having? Also, I assume the missing closing quote and extra closing brace and bracket are typos?

Comment: It should work fine if you add missing single quote after selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if it is a typo or not.. but you are missing a quote.

```
//                v-- this quote was missing
$('#id div.columns').each(function() {
   var div = $(this).attr('argument');
});
```

and also assuming that extra `)};` is a copy/paste mistake..

Answer (score 1):

The .each() handler normally accepts two parameters, the index of the current iteration and the element of the current iteration. You must modify your function to receive these two parameters.

```
$('#id div.columns').each(function(index, element) {

    var div = $(element);
    });         
});
```